# How to get resources directory path programmatically

Tags: java, spring, io

I have the following directory layout:

> - src
>
>   - main
>
>     - java
>     - resources
>
>       - **sql (scripts for database)**
>       - spring (configuration)
>     - webapp

Within a ServletContextListener class, I want to access the files under the SQL directory and list them. Basically my problem is with the path, because I know that listing files under a directory in a nutshell is:

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Maybe I could use the `ServletContextEvent` Object to try and build a path to `resources/sql`

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    event.getServletContext(); //(getRealPath etc.)
}
```

Does something exist to set that path in a relative, non-hardcoded way?
Something like `new File("classpath:sql")` (preferably spring if possible) or what should I do with the servletContext to point at `resources/sql`?

Comment: There are three variants of solution, depending on the situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327069/715269

Comment: See also [How to get the path of src/test/resources directory in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I'm assuming the contents of `src/main/resources/` is copied to `WEB-INF/classes/` inside your .war at build time. If that is the case you can just do (substituting real values for the classname and the path being loaded).

```
URL sqlScriptUrl = MyServletContextListener.class
                       .getClassLoader().getResource("sql/script.sql");
```

Comment: Thanks!! this worked for me, with that URL then I build the Path for the new File, and finally get the files in that directory.

Comment: You don't need the File. You already have a URL. You can't even assume there is a file or a directory at all. The WAR may not have been unpacked.

Comment: What does MyServletContextListener mean here ?

Comment: @TejeshRaut It is a place holder for a class that implements [`javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). I used that as an example because the question had a snippet from `contextInitialized`  which is a method defined by the `ServletContextListener` interface.

Comment: For me it was crucial to prepend the path with `classpath:`, so: `"classpath:/sql/script.sql"`.

Answer (score 76):

Finally, this is what I did:

```
private File getFileFromURL() {
    URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/sql");
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        file = new File(url.getPath());
    } finally {
        return file;
    }
}
```

...

```
File folder = getFileFromURL();
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Comment: Are you sure of using `"/sql"` as the parameter? I have problems with a starting slash, Instead `"sql"` works.

Comment: Please be aware that you can get a different URL with 
this.getClass().getResource("/sql"));

Comment: This won't work on all containers. Tomcat, for example.

Answer (score 20):

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

...

File folder = new ClassPathResource("sql").getFile();
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

It is worth noting that this will limit your deployment options, `ClassPathResource.getFile()` only works if the container has exploded (unzipped) your war file.

Answer (score 11):

Just use **com.google.common.io.Resources** class. Example:

```
 URL url = Resources.getResource("file name")
```

After that you have methods like: **.getContent(), .getFile(),  .getPath() etc**

Comment: Do they also support getting resources while the code is being executed from a jar file?