# How to get the absolute path for JUnit tests

Tags: java

I have a file within my project called x.txt in the same directory as a file that takes x and reads it. However, when using JUnit testing, if I test on a different PC, it will have a different absolute path to the file x.txt

How do I do this so that I dont need to enter the absolute file path, but can hardcode the relative file path for use?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`Class#getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [`Class#getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Examples:

- [How to get resources directory path programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414453/how-to-get-resources-directory-path-programmatically)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html