# How to load folder using classpath in java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to load the entire Mappings folder (which has subfolders and subfolders have files) into the classpath and then want to iterate and find specific files using a hashmap. Using classpath I am able to find the file which is directly loaded under the resources folder but I don't want it that way. Below is my code:

```
public class ClassPathProblem {
    public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception {
        ClassPathProblem cp = new ClassPathProblem();
        cp.loadResource("/Encounter.properties");
    }
    private void loadResource(String resource) throws IOException {
        URL u = this.getClass().getResource(resource);
        loadResourceByUrl(u, resource);
    }
    private void loadResourceByUrl(URL u, String resource) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("-> attempting input resource: " + resource);
        if (u != null) {
            String path = u.getPath();
            path = path.replaceFirst("^/(.:/)", "$1");
            System.out.println("    absolute resource path found :\n    " + path);
            String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
            System.out.println("    file content: " + s);
        } else {
            System.out.println("    no resource found: " + resource);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my project structure for `resources`:

[image]

When I run the program for the input passed it returns the properties file which is loaded directly into the resources folder which is `"Encounter.properties"` but instead of that how can I load the entire mappings folder then iterate according to the way I want?

Comment: You need add the resources in the pom file

Comment: I don't have any pom file such but my actual project has pom files. What should I do exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414453/how-to-get-resources-directory-path-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19459180/

Comment: @Enterman The first link shared by you worked for me. Thanks