# Not getting absolute file path from resources

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, jboss, war

I have a template file under /src/main/resources and i want to get the absolute path of it, the problem is that I'm getting a relative path and not a absolute path.

I need to get the absolute path of the file in my computer after loading the template inside the project. What I'm doing now is this:

```
URL location = this.getClass().getResource("/template/template2.vm"); 
String fullPath = location.getPath();
```

This returns:
    (java.lang.String) vfs:/content/MyProyect-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/templates/template2.vm

If you do it in Eclipse it gives the full path, but deploying in Netbeans and without an IDE returns this result. I'm using jboss for deploying.

I've also tried doing

```
String fullPath = location.getAbsolutePath();
```

and i keep getting this result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327069/715269

Answer (score 3):

JBoss is using Virtual File System (VFS) as stated before. You can get absolute path to file using jboss specific library jboss-vfs.

```
  URL rootUrl = classLoader.getResource(path);
  VirtualFile jbossVirtualFile = (VirtualFile) rootUrl.getContent();
  File fileSystemFile = jbossVirtualFile.getPhysicalFile();
  String absolutePathToFile = fileSystemFile.getPath();
```

Here im using jboss-vfs 3.2.4.Final.

Alternatively if you need to read file and do not care about path use

```
  classLoader.getResourceAsStream(path)
```

(This does not work for dirs.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this always going to be local?  If so can you do this:

```
URL location = this.getClass().getResource(/template/template2.vm); 
File f = new File(location.toUri());
String fullPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: I've already tried with that method. It's not going to be always local.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. JBoss uses different systems for storing deployed files. vfs is one them. I had the same problem some months ago and was not able to solve it, even after a lot of research. I ended up with adding an environment variable when starting jboss pointing to the directory I needed (I needed to load a .properties file, which was outside of the deployment). See here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/PropertiesService

Comment: could you please explain specifically how did you solve the problem? I'm having difficulties trying to solve this problem and i would appreciate your help giving me some feedback and possibly in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thinking about it again, it might not be the best approach for you. You could use your approach, if you would deploy the file outside of jboss (just flat in the file system). I think, this is no option for you. Sorry for the confusion :(