# Creating a new folder in resources folder and read-write text files there (Maven Project)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351043/how-to-get-absolute-path-to-file-in-resources-folder-in-your-project) link to get an idea about how to access files in `resource` directory.

My java file is at `/home/cloudera/Documents/upport/src/main/java/org/mainProject/index/services/SetupService.java` and the resources directory is at `/home/cloudera/Documents/Support/src/main/resources`. I wish to create a folder `config` in resources and write two text files to it.

Copying to any folder using `Files.copy()` gives me `Access Denied`. `mkdir()` and `createDirectory()` were also giving permission errors. So I thought I'll manually copy-paste the files and then access them.

For accessing the files in `resources/config` I tried the following but:

This gives me wrong path:

```
File file = new File("resources/config/file.txt");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

This gives me `null`:

```
SetupService.class.getResource("config/file.txt"));
```

How should I go about it?

Comment: Hint: Keep in mind, that a test case within eclipse, a mvn clean install and your runtime will have different behaviors,... one approach may work for junit, but not during runtime,...

Answer (score 0):

Resources below `src/main/resources/` end up in the JAR file which Maven creates - Java wants it that way. They aren't visible anymore as files when you run the JAR. That's why you can't create a path to them.

To access the resources, you need to ask the `ClassLoader` for a URL (`.getResource("...relative/path...")`) or an `InputStream` (`getResourceAsStream()`).

If you want to save config options, you should use the Preferences API or maybe create a Properties file in the home folder of the user or in a folder defined by a system property.

Related:

- [Accessing Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)
- [Preferences API Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html)

Comment: The `pdfSupport` was a typo. It is basically `Support`. Sorry about that.