# How to Get Absolute Path in Android for File?

Tags: android, csv, android-intent, android-file

```
btnimport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override

 public void onClick(View v) {


 Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

 fileintent.setType("*/*");

            try {

                startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
    });`
```

I'm trying to import sky.csv file in my Android application.

But, when I select file, I'd get:

> IO Exception : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I will check path in:

> LOG  > content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/38F0-D5E4%3ADCIM%2Fsky.csv
>   i'm using this method for getting path
>   `

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{ 

if (data == null)

 return;

switch (requestCode) {

  case requestcode:

 Uri filepath1 = data.getData();

 String filepath = filepath1.toString();
```

Please help me with this. I have tried so many methods. I didn't get any proper solution, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get absolute path to file in /resources folder in your project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351043/how-to-get-absolute-path-to-file-in-resources-folder-in-your-project)

Answer (score 44):

You may want to try the code shown below. It fetch files from device's providers

```
PathUtils.getPath(context, filepath1);
```

`PathUtils.java` class is added below.

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class PathUtils {

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        // DocumentProvider
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {// ExternalStorageProvider
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                String storageDefinition;


                if("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){

                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];

                } else {

                    if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()){
                        storageDefinition = "EXTERNAL_STORAGE";

                    } else{
                        storageDefinition = "SECONDARY_STORAGE";
                    }

                    return System.getenv(storageDefinition) + "/" + split[1];
                }
            
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {// DownloadsProvider

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);

            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {// MediaProvider
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }

        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {// MediaStore (and general)

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);

        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {// File
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Kindly accept this as the correct answer if it helps you with your problem. =) Best regards!

Comment: Thank you kindly!!

Comment: Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable returned false in the emulator and System.getenv(storageDefinition) returned null. System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") is working fine.

Comment: It returned Null for External storage.. works perfectly for interna storage.. please i need this solution and it already took two days to get me in here..
Thanks in advance @DarwinLouis