# Get real path from URI of file in sdcard marshmallow

Tags: android, file, path, uri, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to pick file that exist in sdcard **not in internal storage** and upload it server but I am not able to get its path for getting its size. I have start an intent for pick a file using below code:

```
 intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 intent.setType("*/*");
 String[] mimetypes = {"application/*"};
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
 startActivityForResult(
      Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
```

For getting path to file I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework/20559175#20559175) and its working unless user select any file from sdcard(removable). When I debug the code and found that **type** is not **primary** so it will not go inside this condition :

```
if("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){
     return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
}
```

**So my question is what will be it's else? i.e. what if type is not primary? how we can get path to file in that case?** I have search many questions and tutorial there is no else in any of them. I have also tried else part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295300/how-to-get-absolute-path-in-android-for-file/33298265#33298265) but its not working because `System.getenv()` return **null** for "**SECONDARY_STORAGE**" and **sdcard** for "**EXTERNAL_STORAGE**". I get file not found exception when I try:

```
if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
}else{
    return System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + "/" + split[1];
}
```

Uri and doc Id for file look like:

> **Uri**: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/0EF9-3110%3Adevice-2016-12-02-130553.png
>
> **docId**: 0EF9-3110:device-2016-12-02-130553.png

Any help ??

Comment: Your problem has been reported many times. Every week the last months i think. So just read this site. Further you should explain why you would need a file path. You mostly can do the same with the content scheme you got.

Comment: @greenapps I have already search it and have posted links also.. if you have any link related to my question then please share it

Comment: `my question is what will be it's else? `. You mean 'type'? Well you can tell!

Comment: You did not tell for what you need a file system path.

Comment: @greenapps check now

Comment: You still did not tell for what all the fuss. Why do you need a file system path? Please tell!

Comment: I want to pick file that exist in sdcard and upload it server... but I am not able to get its path

Comment: You do not need a file system path to upload a file to a server. You can use that uri for it! Adapt your code for modern times! Please show part of your upload code.

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni will you pick image or file?

Comment: file can be of any type pdf,image,video,doc ect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After spending time on Android Device Manager I have found solution, here it is:

If doc type id is not primary then I create path using :

```
filePath = "/storage/" + type + "/" + split[1];
```

**EDIT1:** in case of DocumentUri select contentUri on basis of file type

Here is complete function:

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String filePath = "";

    // ExternalStorageProvider
    if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
        final String type = split[0];

        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
                    //getExternalMediaDirs() added in API 21
                    File extenal[] = context.getExternalMediaDirs();
                   for (File f : extenal) {
                    filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    if (filePath.contains(type)) {
                        int endIndex = filePath.indexOf("Android");
                        filePath = filePath.substring(0, endIndex) + split[1];
                    }
                }
             }else{
                    filePath = "/storage/" + type + "/" + split[1];
             }
            return filePath;
        }

    } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
        // DownloadsProvider
        final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        //final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        // Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                String result = cursor.getString(index);
                cursor.close();
                return result;
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
    } else if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // MediaProvider
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String[] ids = wholeID.split(":");
        String id;
        String type;
        if (ids.length > 1) {
            id = ids[1];
            type = ids[0];
        } else {
            id = ids[0];
            type = ids[0];
        }

        Uri contentUri = null;
        if ("image".equals(type)) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        final String selection = "_id=?";
        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{id};
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, 
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return filePath;
    } else {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }


        return filePath;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT2** For handling host like `content://com.adobe.scan.android.documents/document/` check code [here](https://gist.github.com/jaisoni/4d4e20409849dd3cfa12ee15895124a6)

Comment: What should I do for methods "isExternalStorageDocument" and "isDownloadsDocument" ?

Comment: You can find these functions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295300/how-to-get-absolute-path-in-android-for-file/33298265#33298265

Answer (score 3):

Change your upload code. Somewhere you will have

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Change to

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

So use the uri directly. No need for a file path.

Answer (score 0):

​It is quite easy to implement FileProvider on your application. First you need to add a FileProvider tag in AndroidManifest.xml under  tag like below:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And then create a provider_paths.xml file in xml folder under res folder. Folder may be needed to create if it doesn't exist.

res/xml/provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Done! FileProvider is now declared and be ready to use.

The final step is to change the line of code below in MainActivity.java

```
Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(createImageFile());
to



 Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            createImageFile());
```

And .... done ! Your application should now work perfectly fine on any Android version including Android Nougat. Yah !

Comment: can you elaborate your answer? why I need to add this FileProvider in my AndroidManifest??

Comment: Dont give attention to this answer. It's nonsense here. I think that answer belongs to another post as for teaching how to use a file provider its fine.

Comment: My Bad its for the nougat

Comment: This is for when you want to share a file with another application