# How to get uploadable file path link

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to upload a file to the server. To select the file I'm using intent service. I'm using MultiPart file upload. To get the file path I'm using the PathUtils.Java class found in 
[How to Get Absolute Path in Android for File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295300/how-to-get-absolute-path-in-android-for-file)

I'm able to upload files selected from Images and Recents folder. But I'm unable to upload from the Downloads folder. I'm getting null if I select a document in the Downloads folder. Please help.