# How to locate and execute a file with java

Tags: java, path

I am making a game with java as kind of a side project and am still new to the language. I was wondering how I could run a file when i didn't know the complete path, like if I were to send the game to a friend, and he has a different path location than me.
Thank you in advance for any help.

code I am currently using:

```
File file = new File("/Users/(my name)/Desktop/script1.vbs");
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);`
```

Comment: possibile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249167/java-how-to-get-the-correct-absolute-path-of-a-file-within-a-project/43249346#43249346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the file (`script1.vbs`) in the project folder, that way the path would always be like this...

```
File file = new File("script1.vbs")
```

Place the file, not in the `src` or `bin` folder, but in the `root` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
File file = new File("/Users/(my name)/Desktop/script1.vbs");
```

you should better use

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop/script1.vbs");
```

See also the list of [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this, to locate your file in the resources folder:

```
File file = new File("classpath:com/company/script1.vbs");
```

"classpath:Route Of Source folders/Name and extension of the file"