# Passing correct path to a local WSDL file in wsdl2Java task in Gradle Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar, wsdl, wsdl2java

For this web project I need to generate Java classes from some WSDL files (which I have locally in my resources folder) in order to use them in my service. The final aim is to run **jar file** on web server but the program can't find path to WSDL file while running as a jar.

I am using [wsdl2java](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java) to generate these classes and the code, where I do that in my build gradle file, looks like the following:

```groovy
buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.12'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

wsdl2java {
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ['-p', 'wsdlOne', file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlOne.wsdl")],
            ['-p', 'wsdlTwo', file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlTwo.wsdl")],
            ['-p', 'wsdlThree', file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlThree.wsdl")],
            ['-p', 'wsdlFour', file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlFour.wsdl")],
            ['-p', 'wsdlFive', file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlFive.wsdl")],
    ]
}
```

// More lines here...

Project works fine locally, but when I run jar file on the server and test the service which uses WSDL, it crashes with the following exception:

```html
Exception: Failed to access the WSDL at: file:/D:/projects/my_project/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlOne.wsdl. It failed with:
    /D:/projects/my_project/src/main/resources/wsdl/wsdlOne.wsdl (No such file or directory).
```

I could replace local addresses of WSDL files with their real http addresses on the web, but I am required to leave them as they are now.

I researched a lot and tried all the possible solutions but I could not find any that would work for my case. I have looked thoroughly (I hope so) through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351043/how-to-get-absolute-path-to-file-in-resources-folder-of-your-project) and answers but without results.

If useful in anything, [here](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) is the link to see the list of all the optional arguments that can be used to customize code generated from WSDL files by wsdl2Java and you can view the description of wsdl2java gradle plugin [here](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java).

I would be very grateful if anyone could give even a slightest hint about what I am missing here.